# master theorem and recurrence

Tags: algorithm, recurrence, master-theorem

I am given a recurrence
T(n) = 3T(n/2) + n^2 lg(n)

Is it possible to use master theorem to find a T(n) = theta(f(n))? There is polylogarithmic function as f(n) but as I understand there is a limited 4th case. Would that 4th case apply here?

Answer (score 0):

[Master's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) does not have any constrains with regards to a f(n) function:

[image]

So your a = 3, b = 2, so c = log2(3), and you fall in the third case and the solution is `O(n^2 log n)`